# can't open sound file although the path is right tried ./ , ../ , ../../ and none worked

Tags: javascript, path

Trying to make a blackjack game and my error appears when I press the hit button a king card picture should appear and also sound should play but the sound doesn't play and this error appears **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** [image]

here is my paths to the project folder[image]

I tried to change the way of typing the source like /statics , ../../statics but it didn't work

and here is the needed part of my code to understand:

html part

```
    <div class="playerContainer">
        <div class="playerChoice">
            <h1 id="playerScore"> You: <span id="playerResult"> 0 </span> </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="botChoice">
            <h1 class="dealerResult"> Computer: <span id="dealerResult"> 0 </span> </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button id="standBtn"class="btn-lg btn-warning mr-2">stand</button>
        <button id="dealBtn"class="btn-lg btn-danger mr-2">deal</button>
        <button id="hitBtn"class="btn-lg btn-primary mr-2">hit</button>
    </div>
```

Js part

```
let blackJackGame = {
    'you' : {'scoreSpan':'#playerResult','div': '.playerChoice', 'score': 0},
    'bot' : {'scoreSpan':'#dealerResult','div': '.botChoice', 'score': 0}
};

const YOU = blackJackGame['you'];
const BOT = blackJackGame['bot'];
const hitSound = new Audio('../statics/sounds/Ta Da-SoundBible.com-1884170640');

document.querySelector('#hitBtn').addEventListener('click',blackJackHit);

function blackJackHit() {
    let cardImage = document.createElement('img');
    cardImage.src = 'B:/Html, CSS & Js/js excersing/photos/KS.png'
    document.querySelector(YOU['div']).appendChild(cardImage);
    hitSound.play();
}
```

the error occurs in this js line

```
const hitSound = new Audio('../statics/sounds/Ta Da-SoundBible.com-1884170640');
```

Comment: if it's from your `index.html`, I think you just need `/sounds/Ta Da-SoundBible.com-1884170640`

Comment: Just tried and the same error appears

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add the audio file extension at the end of the path.
2. It seems that the right path should be `../sounds/file.extension`.

Since you're using VSCode, I recommend using the [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) extension to make similar situations easier in the future.

Comment: If you mean to add .extension after the file name I have done that and the same error appears.

Comment: Have you tried to use the path i suggested in point 2 in addition to using the file extension? 
And have you given Path Intellisense  a try if suggestions above are failing?

Comment: Yes I have tried to do exactly what you said but unfortunately it didn't work but I didn't try the extension because I need to reinstall vbcode In order for them to work

Comment: I just tried the extension and it worked to locate the file but it runs with the same problem

Comment: are you sure that the mentioned error is related to the audio file not the image with this absolute path? `B:/Html, CSS & Js/js excersing/photos/KS.png` please try replacing it with a relative path and make sure the error is not related to it and check if it's appearing, and if it's not the case, make sure the file is not corrupted and try playing it and le tme know.

Comment: yes I am sure because the image appears when I hit the button + the terminal locates the error at the sound file and also at first the same error at the sound file appeared at the image file and when I wrote the absolute path it worked fine I tried to do the same thing with the sound file but it did't work

Comment: I tried playing the file and it's working fine and not corrupted.

Comment: I also tried to do what you said in your last comment for the photo path and the error returns again.

Comment: OK, last thing i can think of that might be causing this issue is the spaces in the filename  so please rename the file to a short name without spaces like `tada.mp3` and modify the path in the script to match the new filename then save and retry

Comment: ok it didn't work but thanks a lot for your time and I appreciate your help.